# useEffect hook not working properly while calling onAuthStateChanged

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, firebase-authentication

I am able to login a user successfully using Firebase. In my code, after the user has successfully logged in, they are directed to their profile. My problem is that whenever I refresh the browser, the user is logged out for a split second and then directed back to their profile. If I'm on any other page, the user is completely logged out. I'm quite new to custom hooks and am trying to learn on the job. Here's my code

```
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState("")
const [currentUserData, setCurrentUserData] = useState("")
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {

            if (user) {
                setCurrentUser(user)
                db.collection('users')
                    .doc(user.uid)
                    .get()
                    .then(doc => {
                        setCurrentUserData(doc.data())
                        // MUST REARANGE vvvv
                        history.push('/')
                    })
                setLoading(false)
            }
            else {
                setCurrentUser(null)
                setCurrentUserData(null)
            }

        })
        return unsubscribe
    }, [history])
```

Comment: Seems you need to persist your authentication state so it can be reinitialized into state when the component mounts. You may also need a third "state" between authenticated and unauthenticated, like a "loading" or "pending" state so you don't prematurely log out users.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply @DrewReese . How do I persist the authentication state when the component mounts? I am adding in the loading feature now

Comment: A typical solution is to use localStorage to persist state periodically. Check local storage when the component mounts.

Comment: @BrandonAustin were you able to find the solution for the above problem. I am in the same boat.